# How does plugin specific configuration gets interpreted during runtime

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a parent POM which defines `maven-compiler-plugin` definition/configuration under `pluginManagement.plugins.plugin`.

I have a multi-module project which has a requirement to re-define the configuration for their respective modules (e.g. moduleA, moduleB). Since the definitions are inherited can I be assured that configuration specific to moduleA, moduleB will be used while performing the build.

e.g. moduleA wants to use jdk 1.5 to compile and moduleB wants to use JDK 1.6 to compile.

How should this be defined in the POM files? Do I need to define anything in the parent POM or should I just define compiler-plugin with respective configurations on moduleA, moduleB.

Comment: Why do you have different compiler settigns for different modules in the same project?

Comment: we have a legacy module to support, which runs in a different environment.

Comment: As i wrote you can simply define the configuration for the compiler-plugin into the appropriate module.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just define the compiler plugin with its appropriate configuration part which you need. But don't define the version of the compiler plugin this is inherited via the pluginManagement part.